# Calculating uncertainty of predictions - standard error or error calculus?

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-error, error-propagation, inverse-prediction

I'm looking to create a calibration function for a lab instrument I have:

$y = A + Bx$

Where $y$ is the "true" output and $x$ is the initial reading. I have a dataset of ~100 readings that I can apply OLS and obtain $A$ and $B$. My values for $y$ and $x$ are quite far away from the origin, but I still think that $A$ has valuable information, so I'm not sure whether centering my data will help here.

Here are the results of my OLS fit using statsmodels in Python:

[image]

My problem is that want to also calculate the uncertainty in any future value of $y$ I calculate using the fitted equation. From what I understand, I have two possible approaches:

1. Using simple error propagation, I could use the standard errors reported for $A$ and $B$ to calculate: $\sigma_{y} = \sqrt{\sigma_{A}^{2} + \sigma_{B}^{2}x^{2}}$. However, because $x$ and $\sigma_{A}$ are quite large, I'm going to get an unrealistically high value for $\sigma_{y}$.
2. Just calculate the standard error of prediction using: $\sigma_{y} = \hat\sigma_{x}\sqrt{1/n+(x_j-\bar{x})^2/\Sigma{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}$. This approach produces much more sensible values for my data, but it is rather cumbersome to have to also have to record $n$ and $\bar{x}$ when estimating the uncertainty of future $y$ observations.

Why don't these methods give the same answer, and which is the "right" one to use for future $y$ measurements?

Comment: If you don't want to do it yourself, use `results.get_prediction(ex)` in statsmodels.

Comment: Your application of OLS is incorrect, because all the errors are in the $X$ variable whereas OLS requires that the errors be entirely in the $Y$ variable.  For a better approach see our [threads on calibration and inverse regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibration+regression+inverse).

Comment: @whuber: Thank you. That aside, which method is more defensible?

Comment: Neither.  For effective, defensible methods consult the threads I linked to.